# ActiveRecord created_at and enforcing sequential consistency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

When is the created_at field assigned a timestamp? When the model object is created, or when the db transaction completes?

Basically I want to make sure that I can  rely on the sequential consistency of the database (Postgres). As an example: I have a chat system where users pull for new messages with the time stamp (aka - give me all my messages that are newer than time X) -  I want to make sure that the user sees a consistent snapshot of the database.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveRecord callbacks `after_validation` and `before_create` can be used to test this.

When you create a new model object, the `created_at` field is nil during the `after_validation` callback, but present during the `before_create` callback, which suggests that the `created_at` timestamp is recorded just before the model is actually persisted to the database (but after model-level validations occur).

It looks as though you can override the default rails behavior for this by setting `config.active_record.record_timestamps = false`.  You can then assign the `created_at` field at whatever point in the process you want.  Hopefully that helps answer your question!

Here's more info about Timestamps (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html) and Callbacks (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Comment: Thanks! Though it's kinda weird to set the timestamp after the object is created - it requires am extra save (trip to the DB), and doesn't solve the consistency problem